# why my conditional statement does not work?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am beginner to python. When I type in ontario to the input function 'province', it turns the tax value of 0.05. Why is that? I want it to turn 0.13. What's wrong here?
Thanks!

```
country = input('Where are you from? ')

if country.lower() == 'canada':
    province = input('which province are you living in? :')
    if province.lower() == 'alberta' or 'nunavut':
        tax = 0.05
    elif province.lower() == 'ontario': #elif 
        tax = 0.13
    else:
        tax = 0.15
    print('your tax is ' + str(tax)) 


else:
    print("Welcome tourist, you don't pay any taxes")
```

Comment: `or` combines the two "boolean" expressions `province.lower() == 'alberta'` and `'nunavut'`; it does not "distribute" over `==` to produce two equality tests.

Comment: As a boolean, `'nunavut'` (a non-empty string) is always true, and `x or True` is always true.

Comment: change `if province.lower() == 'alberta' or 'nunavut':` to `if province.lower() in ['alberta' , 'nunavut']:`